# encrypt/decrypt passwords with node.js

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I am working with the `bcrypt` nodejs module.

I am satisfied with it to encrypt and compare passwords, but it seems impossible to decrypt it.

I am wondering:

1. How do you encrypt/decrypt passwords with nodejs (which module or method are you using) ?
2. Is there a trick to decrypt the passwords encoded with the `bcrypt` module ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't decrypt passwords with bcrypt -- it's a one-way algorithm. What you do is store the hash of the original (salted) password. Then you hash the (salted) guess. If the hashes match, then the guess is correct.

Fortunately, the `node-bcrypt` library does all of this for you, so you only need to provide the plaintext guess and the hash (from the database).

For example, you might do this:

```
// "password"; usually stored in the database in the user's row.
var stored_hash = '$2a$10$vxliJ./aXotlnxS9HaJoXeeASt48.ddU7sHNOpXC/cLhgzJGdASCe'
bcrypt.compare(guess, stored_hash, function(err, res) {

});
```

Comment: Yes that's what i did but if you want to auth a user using an external API, for example facebook, and return the credentials of this same user to the client side, it could be usefull.

Comment: @Ludo Do you need to know their password or do you just need to know their name and whether they could succesfully logged in? This is what axternal login APIs like Facebook connect provide, authentication is made on facebook.com, not on your domain and facebook redirects the user to appopriate path you specified with its hash and then you know that user is authenticated.

Comment: @Mustafa I need a password i automatically generate on the server side during the facebook registration to display it on the admin page of the user.

Comment: You should not display a password to the user. They should know their password, and in the event that they forget it, offer some mechanism to create a new one (perhaps by emailing a link to reset to their registered email). Openly displaying a users password to them is a horrible idea (no offense). Imagine a situation where someone hijacks a session. If the hijacked users password is displayed to the hijacker, the hijacker now has the actual password, not just session access. For this same reason you should require the password to be entered on changes to sensitive information.

Comment: If you auto-generate it, email it to them ONCE, or display it ONCE during sign up. After this you should never need to openly show them their password.

Comment: After you auto-generate the password and email it to them, you should strongly consider treating this as a temporary password, and force them to reset it. See, for example: http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/05/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know.html